# Podocarpus leaves cannot tear seed shell

Tags: germination

I ordered podocarpus seeds, they gave roots but the issue is that they begin to grow and the seeds soon were raised above the ground but the leaves don't come out of the seed shell. They don't seem to have the strength to do it. So from 10 germinated seeds only one was success.

I thought that maybe I should plant germinated seeds deeper, but again the seeds are raising but the leaves are still in the shell.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried soaking or scoring the seed before planting? Scarification and stratification are two methods to help plants break through hard seeds shells. Try some of the methods on this site:

http://www.rodalesorganiclife.com/garden/pretreatments-slow-germinate-seeds

Comment: Thanks, but your answer it generally wrong, these seeds don't need stratification, and scarification is deadly for them cause they are very vulnerable. I will soon prepare instructions with photos, I made a lot of experiments and achieved success.